# Transactions reverting

Tags: openzeppelin, gnosis-safe, openzeppelin-contracts, gnosis

So the thing is I am trying to make a smart contract with multi sig. However, it's showing this error when I am trying to transfer ownership:

> Transaction would revert. Check that permissions, balances, and other function requirements are valid for the transaction you want to run.

This is the contract and the code is available at it :

> 0xBc2cd7aEe058F3D749E598FF105e8Ac0daA0f56a

Comment: what network are you on?

Comment: How do you create the transaction? Have you tried executing it and then looking at the trace? Please add more information

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.